# Animations with Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, material-design

As far as I have seen, there are no support for animations in the current (v0.9.0) Angular Material Design library. It's neither documented at official docs. Although it is explained breafly at Google Material Design apecification.

So, how should we go ahead implementing animations, and in particular state trantitions, with Angular? I believe that there are different alternatives such as use of CSS, JQuery, ++ but what direction should we aim for?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material doesn't aim to provide any animations. It provides css classes that you can use to "link" your own animations to (enter/leave classes).

Also the official angular page to animation states:

> Animations in AngularJS are completely based on CSS classes.

So probably this should be the way to go. Also because regarding animations nowadays you can do almost everything with pure CSS (no js needed).

As far as I read, many use animate.css in combination with Angular Material.